# How to display all users in my custom view in Treeline

Tags: treeline

I created a route w/ a GET & list users, that gets all my users. Then I selected :

```
display view  “users” and data
```

How do I loop through these users (the data) and display them in my users.ejs file?

Is there something like

```
<% users.each do |user| %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In treeline make sure you send down an object with the user data. It would look like so:

[image: Users response]

Then in your .ejs file you can loop through the users like so:

```
<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
  // Some HTML using user
<% }) %>
```

Edit: Added missing parens